# StorageService returning callback Ionic2/Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm having a lot of problems with my Asyncronous calls to the Storage, on my console.log it shows first line 50 and then line 20... I'd like to avoid this.

I have a service where I have calls to my Storage but all returns a Promise and everywhere I call them I have to do `.then().catch()` so it's giving me problems... How can I do that methods returns with a callback? So I can call my method and don't think about Asyncronous?

An example of my `StorageService` is

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

//Storage
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';


@Injectable()
export class StorageServiceProvider {

    constructor(public http: Http, private storage: Storage) {
    }

    saveUser(user) {
        if (user== null) return;
        var userToSave= { "id": user["id"], "info": user["info"] };
        this.storage.set('userStored', JSON.stringify(userToSave));
    }
    //I'd like to do it like this, but I can't because Asyncronous so I have to do it like this.storage.get('userStored');
    getUserId() {
        this.storage.get('userStored').then((idUser) => {
            return JSON.parse(idUser["id"]);
        })
            .catch((err: any) => {
                console.log("Err");

            });

    }
    //I'm testing this now
    getUserInfo() {
        return this.storage.get("userStored");

    }
    //RestsLocalStorage
    resetLocalStorage() {
        this.storage.clear();
    }

}
```

And for example I'd like to have a method that returns to me an `id` and other the `info` but only know how to do it getting the `object`...

The call from the component is like this ...

```
this.storageServiceProvider.getUserInfo().then((information) => {
    var infoStored = JSON.parse(information)["info"];
    console.log(infoStored );
    //if..else
  })
    .catch((err: any) => {
      console.log("Error");

    });

 }
```

And in other method I need to call both of them... and I want to avoid 2 then and catch... I'd like do it something like this :

```
let userInfo= this.storageServiceProvider.getUserInfo;
let userId= this.storageServiceProvider.getUserId;
```

I've an old project (`Ionic1/Angluar1`) and I did something like this :

```
angular.module('app.storageServices', [])
.factory ("storageService", ['$localStorage',function ($localStorage) {

    var saveUser = function (user) {      
      if(user==null) return;
      $localStorage.userId=user.id;
      $localStorage.userInfo=user.info;
    };

    var getIdUser = function () {
      if($localStorage.userId!=null){
        return $localStorage.userId;    
      }
      return null;
    };
    var getInfoUser = function () {
      if($localStorage.info!=null){     
        return $localStorage.info;  
      }
      return null;
    };

    return {
        saveUser: saveUser,
        getIdUser: getIdUser,
        getInfoUser: getInfoUser       
    };
}])
```

And I only was calling the methods like this :

```
this.myTestFunction=function(success,error){

    var userId=storageService.getUserId();
    if(userId!=null && userId!=""){
        var userInfo=storageService.getUserInfo();
        //if..else 
    }else{
        console.log("error");           
    }       
}
```

So could I have something like my old project with >=ionic2 and >=Angular2?

What I'm missing?

Comment: so you'd like to convert your promise/observable call to a synchronous one? I don't think it's a good idea thou and I would not do it

Comment: Then @crash can you tell me how can I get the values using promise/observable calls?

Comment: it depends on how you want to use it, there's no real need to convert it to an observable... you can do it with `Observable.fromPromise()` but it will behave the same way as a promise, you can leverage all the methods of the observables so you'll have a lot of flexibility, but it will be asynchronous anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create a synchronous call when working with asynchronous code. The point of asynchronous code is that you don't have the result immediately, so you have to wait until it's available. There is no way around that.

In your example I don't understand why you have two different get methods, one for the `userId` and one for `userInfo`. Because both values are stored in the same place you can just use `getUserInfo()` and then access `id`, `info` or whatever property you need.

But let's say your code is only an example and you really need multiple get functions. You have 2 options:

In your `StorageServiceProvider` you return promises.

```
getUserId() {
    return this.storage.get('userIdStored');
}

getUserInfo() {
    return this.storage.get("userInfoStored");
}
```

You can then use `Promise.all()` to wait for all promises to resolve at once.

```
Promise.all([this.storageServiceProvider.getUserId(), this.storageServiceProvider.getUserInfo()])
.then(values => {
  console.log(values); // [userId, userInfo]
});
```

The other option would be to use the new `async/await` syntax:

```
async function() {
  let userId = await this.storageServiceProvider.getUserId();
  let userInfo = await this.storageServiceProvider.getUserInfo()
  // Note: This is synchronous, so the 2 Promises are not executed in parallel. Read more here: https://medium.com/@bluepnume/learn-about-promises-before-you-start-using-async-await-eb148164a9c8
}
```

EDIT:

If you only what to get the User ID you have to create your own promise and resolve with the value you need:

```
getUserId() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.storage.get('userInfo')
      .then(user => {
        resolve(user.id);
      })
      .catch(reject);
  });
}
```

`getUserId()` will now resolve a promise that resolves with the userId, so you can use it like that:

```
this.storageServiceProvider.getUserId().then(id => {
  console.log(id); // UserID
})
```

or

```
async myFunction() {
  let userId = await this.storageServiceProvider.getUserId();
  console.log(userId);
}
```

Comment: let me test the first one, and I'll let you know if it's ok or not

Comment: it's returning to me something like this : `(2) ["{"id":"0","info":"hellooo"}", undefined]
0
:
"{"id":"0","info":"hellooo"}"
1
:
undefined`

Comment: I'd like to get the id directly when I call this.storageServiceProvider.getUserId() I mean doing this I'd like to get for example 0, and if I do return this.storage.get("userInfoStored"); it will return this : "{"id":"0","info":"hellooo"}"

Comment: I updated my answer. Like I said before, it's not possible to make this synchronous. The only other thing you could do is to store the id directly into a class variable in your StorageServiceProvider, then you can simply return that value synchronously. But then you have to assume that the value has not been initialised yet. But I would definitely recommend the version with the promises because there it is less error prone.

Comment: I can't return an int instead of a promise?

Comment: Well, if it's better the promises way, I guess you mean this `return this.storage.get("userInfoStored");` , if I do this, I get by console this ["{"id":"0","info":"hellooo"}", "{"id":"0","info":"hellooo"}"]

Comment: By the "promises way" I mean the "EDIT" part of my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148065/discussion-between-stuart2041-and-andreas-gassmann).